# AWS Lambda: Getting a return value from lambda and using in Cloud Formation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a Lambda that checks if network configurations are present in an AWS account.
I have invoked this lambda as part of an stack execution (this is an Cloud formation template).

Now the Lambda invoked will return a Dictionary as a response/return value. How to save this response in a Calling CFN template and fetch the value in the Dictionary and use this value as a Condition variable in the Cloud Formation template further?

Comment: Can you show us your template? Are you using a macro?

Comment: Not sure if this is possible (may be, may not be) but example of a custom resource [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-custom-resources-lambda-lookup-amiids.html) that uses Fn::GetAtt and a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53738689/create-a-resource-based-on-condition-block-which-takes-output-from-custom-resou).